# With Python i want to post on facebook timeline, but not using API, whats wrong?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to make a code to login on facebook with Python and post on facebook timeline, but not using facebook API because i dont like it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import datetime
import time 


username = "email@gmail.com"
password = "bigverybigpassword"


print("--->: HUE HUE HUE BRASIL ")

#options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\files_python\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

print("--->: login_button")
login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_b")
login_button.submit()
time.sleep(5)

first_what_is_on_my_mind_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_5qtp")
first_what_is_on_my_mind_element.click()
time.sleep(3)

second_what_is_on_my_mind_element = driver.switch_to.active_element
second_what_is_on_my_mind_element.send_keys("test")

# posting
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._1mf7._4jy0._4jy3._4jy1._51sy.selected._42ft")
button.clicke()


print("--->: FIM BRASIL ")
```

But i get this error:

```
[1256:1520:0828/171216.101:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [17:12:16.100] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\files_python\get_all_channels_youtube\log_at_youtube.py", line 106, in <module>
    button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._1mf7._4jy0._4jy3._4jy1._51sy.selected._42ft")
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 598, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._1mf7._4jy0._4jy3._4jy1._51sy.selected._42ft"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

Comment: Hi, there can you just post the html tag that you need from the page. Or while inspecting the page just copy the xpath. It seems you are using the css selector instead of something like class or an id.  Which may be the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def posttimeline(username,password):
    try:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
        browser.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(username)
        browser.find_element_by_name("pass").send_keys(password)
        browser.find_element_by_name('login').click()
        time.sleep(20)        
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div').send_keys("Hello world")
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div').click()
        time.sleep(12)
        browser.close()
        browser.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occured : ",e)


posttimeline("username","password")
```